# Why is debug_backtrace() using so much memory?

Tags: php, memory

When trying to trace some memory issues in PHP, I noticed that `debug_backtrace()`, which I call in my logging code, seemed to be using a lot of memory.

In most cases, the following code prints something like `0.02 MB`. But in one case, it prints `171.85 MB`!

```
$before = memory_get_usage();
$backtrace = debug_backtrace(false);
$after = memory_get_usage();
echo round(($after - $before)/1024/1024, 2)." MB";
```

My question is, does this mean that `debug_backtrace` is actually using that much memory? Or could something else be happening, like garbage collection, that messes up the return value from `memory_get_usage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured it out. I printed out the backtrace, and the `"args"` array was huge. This is because I was passing around some enormous strings. I guess it's making copies of them (instead of references) when returning the results.

For example:

```
function test($str) {
    test2($str);
}
function test2($str) {
    test3($str);
}
function test3($str) {
    echo "before: ".round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024, 2)." MB\n";
    debug_backtrace(false);
    echo "after: ".round(memory_get_usage()/1024/1024, 2)." MB\n";
}
test(str_repeat('a', 10000000));
```

Try this with and without the debug_backtrace() call. With it, the memory usage is increased by about 28 MB. It's only cleared when test3() returns.

Comment: I think you're thinking of pass by reference and pass by value.  The output from `debug_backtrace()` is an array of the values.  If you recurively call a function 100 times with the string "Hello World!!!", 100 copies of that string will be in the array.  But in your application there will be only one instance of it with 100 references to it until they are modified.

Comment: Glad you found your solution.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down-voted...this was definitely the cause of the issue.

Comment: Since PHP 5.3.6 you can keep that from happening by passing DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS to debug_backtrace! :D 
before: 9.84 MB
after: 9.84 MB

Answer (score 7):

Its the objects, most likely, that are causing the bloat.  Try passing `false` to the function so you don't pull the objects and your traces will be much smaller.

EDIT: If passing `false` doesn't work then if you're running PHP 5.3.6+ you can use a bitmask to limit what the function returns.  What it sounds like is that you have objects being passed as args that are huge.

[http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Additionally if you are using PHP 5.4.0+ they added a second param that will allow you to limit the number of stack frames.

EDIT2: total <<**HACK**>> here, but works ... add a try/catch, throw an exception and catch it then convert to string or call exception getTraceAsString() to get the full stack.  Example:

```
try {
    throw new Exception('ignore this string');
} catch(Exception $e) {
    /* @var $trace array */
    $trace = $e->getTrace();

    // OR

    /* @var $str string */
    $str = $e->getTraceAsString();
    $e = null;
}
```

In the above snipped you can use `$trace` and build your own output or just use the standard exception as string `$str`.  Easier to get the stack frame output.

Comment: This makes sense, but I just tried it, and I still get the huge memory increase.

Comment: @JW.  Added a <<<***HACK***>>> that uses `Exception`

Comment: This can be done without try catch like this:
  $e = new Exception();
  $value = $e->getTraceAsString();

Answer (score 2):

If your code is for example recursive and you are deep into the recursion, the backtrace would have to store data for each recursion ...

Comment: I tried printing out the count of `$backtrace` after the large memory increase, which should indicate the number of levels of function calls, but it was only 8.

Comment: @JW: Hmm, sorry. In this case I'm out of ideas on this one.