# How to avoid “memory … exhausted” error when using debug_backtrace() in custom error handler?

Tags: php, error-handling, custom-error-handling

I wrote an error handler for my website that looks like this:

```
function errorHandler($number, $string, $file, $line, $context, $type = '') {
// save stuff in DB
}
```

Which I register like this:

```
set_error_handler('errorHandler', E_ALL);
```

I save all of the passed variables in a DB, as well as a backtrace to help me debug the problem:

```
print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT), true)
```

The problem is that I sometimes get this error:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 30084081 bytes)

The reason the error handler was run when it gave the above error was that I tried to use an undefined variable *after* having created an Amazon S3 object (from their PHP AWS library). I'm assuming since the Amazon AWS library is so huge that the backtrace is pulling in a ton of data, which causes the out of memory error (?).

I want to include a backtrace when possible to help with debugging, but how do I prevent calling the `debug_backtrace()` function from causing a fatal error (inside my error handler, which is kind of ironic..)?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175969/why-is-debug-backtrace-using-so-much-memory

Comment: @CharlieS I had seen that, but unfortunately there isn't a solution presented there that works.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you simply need to remove the DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT

It could be that your code has circular references in the objects that mean that when dumping them it loops until all memory is  consumed.

Another alternative way to do this is to throw and catch an Exception and then use this to get your backtrace

```
try{
  throw new Exception();
}catch(Exception $e){
  echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php

Or if you need verbosity then try print_r($e->getTrace());

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettrace.php

Comment: This works perfectly when `debug_backtrace()` fails should be marked as the answer

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend if at all possible replacing `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT` with `DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

Answer (score 3):

You could set a limit to your debug_backtrace.

```
print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT, 50), true);
```

[PHP debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

Comment: Good idea, but it didn't work unfortunately. I even tried changing `50` to `1` and it still runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

first check if it is really memory which is exhausting.
once i had this error which i traced to an infinite loop.

since your server does not allow ini_set , i suggest you to copy it at a local system and increase memory to 1gb and check if memory still get exhausted ,it is an infinite loop .

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best answer but have you considered using var_dump instead of print_r?  var_dump only goes down a couple of nesting levels so the issues with circular references that edmondscommerce mentioned would not cause your memory to become exhausted.

Comment: This works perfectly. It may not get you everything you need, but it gets you something, which is better than nothing and timeout.

Comment: `var_dump` goes all the way down unless XDebug extension is installed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase memory limit:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
print_r(debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT), true);
```

Comment: This would probably work, but I don't think that's a realistic solution for a production server for two reasons: 1) I think `ini_set()` is disabled for security reasons and 2) If it really were to take up that much memory when an error occurred, then a few simultaneous errors would use up the entire server's memory.

Comment: I just show you the way, you can increase memory limit in .htaccess/php.ini/etc. If you want use DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT you should increase current memory limit, no doubt. But if you want to get debug info without changing settings, use $e->getTraceAsString() as edmondscommerce described below.